# Put multiple datasets names into a list saved as objects of class pointer

Tags: r, dataframe, append, lapply

I have a function that saves dataframes as pointers. This saves time and space to execute large dataframes.

```
newPointer=function(inputValue){  
object=new.env(parent=globalenv())  
object$value=inputValue  
class(object)='pointer'
return(object)  
}
df1<-newPointer(data.frame(col1=c(1:10),col2=c(1:10)))
df2<-newPointer(data.frame(col1=c(11:20),col2=c(11:20)))
```

So to retrieve the value I have to type

```
`dataframe1<-df1$value`
```

I have number of such dataframes with pattern "dataframe". 
I have this command to combine the dataframes into a list by pattern:

```
datalist <- lapply(ls(pattern="dataframe"), function(x) get(x))
```

But this gives list of pointers

I try to do get(x$value).  Gives an error-

```
datalist <- lapply(ls(pattern="dataframe"), function(x) get(x$value))
Error in x$value : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

My final aim is to append all dataframes into one dataframe using

```
big_data = bind_rows(datalist)
```

How do I get the list of dataframes instead of the pointers using laaply() or is there any better way to do combine dataframes (not pointers) and append together.